# When to use trait components, objects, package objects in Scala

Tags: scala, singleton, object, component, trait

When I am adding dependencies in Scala, I tend to use mixin trait components for those that are inherit to the class itself.  For example, `DaoGenerator extends Generator`

However, for trait components likes `FileIO`, it is less straight-forward.  If the `DaoGenerator` class requires it, I tend to make a judgement call.  I feel like it can be either a `trait component`, `object`, or `package object`.

If it is part of the classes "responsibility", I add it as trait component.  A generator class will most likely need to access file objects in the project so I add it as a `trait component`.

But if it was any other class, I tend to like to add it as either an `object` or `package object`, simply because it is cross-cutting concern.  But when do you choose an `object` over a `package object`? For logging and configuration, I use `package object` only because it feels right.

What's your rule of thumb for these cases?